# not able to connect to work light development server from iOS device(work light 6.2)

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Could somebody help me for the below issue:

I am not able to connect to work light development server from iOS device(work light 6.2)
It works fine in worklight emulator and Xcode simulator. 
Do I need to do any change in the device settings to connect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better had you provided any errors you see in Xcode Console or in the Details view in the app, available when the application fails to connect to the Worklight Server.

Anyway, the usual culprit would be if the device is not connected to the same network as the development server. Make sure both are connected to the same network.